# Obtener Id del item actual en List de Sapui5

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una lista de forma dinámica, de la cual necesito obtener el id del item seleccionado. Éste es un ejemplo. En los Alert se debería de devolver el id actual.

Agradecería que en lugar de corregir la forma de escribir u otra cosa me dieran alguna respuesta a mi pregunta.

¿Alguna idea?. Gracias

```js
var oListData = [{id: "id-1",text:"Hello World"},
            {id: "id-2",text:"Hello Universe"}];
   
var oListModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oListData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oListModel);


// create the main List control
var list = new sap.m.List({
});


var oCustomItem = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
  content: [
    new sap.m.Text({
      text: "{text}"}),
    new sap.m.Button({
      text: "btn",
      press: function(oEvent){
                    alert(id-1);
                  }
              })
  ],
  press: function(oEvent){
                    alert("id-1");
          }
      });

list.bindAggregation("items", "/", oCustomItem);

var page = new sap.m.Page({
  title: "List Page",
  content : list
});

var app = new sap.m.App({
  pages: [page]
}).placeAt("content");
```

```html
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout" 
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"></script>
```

Comment: Ya encontré la solución. Gracias

Comment: Si has encontrado la respuesta estaria bien que la escribieses. De esta manera si alguna vez a alguien le surge este mismo problema podra encontrar aqui la solución.

Comment: Agradeceríamos si agregaras la solución que encontraste como Respuesta. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

La solución que pude encontrar es:

```
var hB =  new sap.m.HBox({
   items:[
        new sap.m.VBox({
            items:[new sap.m.Text({text: "{codigo}"}), new sap.m.Text({text: "{descripcion}"})]
        }).addStyleClass("navigationItem"),
        new sap.m.Button({
            icon: "sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow", 
            press: function (oEvent) {
                var oContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
                var cod = oContext.getProperty("codigo");   
                alert(cod);
            }
        }).addStyleClass("customsapMBtnInner")
    ]
});

var oCustomItem = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
    content: [hB],
    type :sap.m.ListType.Active,
    press: function (oEvent) {
        var oContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
        //console.log(oContext.getObject());
        var cod = oContext.getProperty("codigo");
        alert(cod);
        }
    }
});
```

si alguien tiene una mejor idea, espero lo comparta. Gracias